# Keeping Tyr's favor

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

The Forgotten Realms' [wiki for the Church of Tyr](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Church_of_Tyr) states that

> To keep Tyr's favor, one must respect fallen enemies, never make sacrifice of a corpse, and keep one's alignment lawful good.

What do the two first conditions entail? I would take the "respecting fallen enemies" to mean not mocking/defiling defeated enemies, but what about "making sacrifice of a corpse"? Not to raise it as undead?

Comment: This appears to be a "what does this English phrase mean?" question, which is off topic here but can be asked at [elu.se] or [ell.se].

Comment: Dolgan, I asked this question over on English SE, and Seven [provided an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/284678/70061) good enough for me to accept.